# Can Google App Engine be used as a mediator server for HTTP while using HTTP tunnel?

Tags: http, google-app-engine, networking

How can I set up Google App Engine be used as a mediator server for HTTP while using HTTP tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because App Engine apps cannot make arbitrary TCP connections.

Comment: Is there any servers which can be used for this purpose? Any free?

Comment: @RCola That isn't really on-topic for SO.